# Does Lucene support searching between multiple index documents?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

In Database :

I have two tables. and there are three columns in each table.
Table_A (column_primaryKey_A,column_A1,column_A2)
Table_B (column_primaryKey_B,column_B1,column_B2)

Below is the SQL that I want to do using Lucene:
**SELECT** * **FROM** Table_A,Table_B **WHERE** column_primaryKey_A = column_primaryKey_B **AND** column_A1 = XX **AND** column_B1 = XX

I want to create two index documents（**Index_Table_A**, **Index_Table_A**）and **how do I implement above things using the mechanism of Lucene or Hibernate Search?**.

Any help will be thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why do you need to indexes or why do you want to use lucene in the first place, but I can tell you how to implement it using one index. (using two indexes is possible but is significantly less performance)

Using one index, index any document as following:

```
title = column_primaryKey_A
column_A1 = val...
column_A2 = val2...
column_B1 = val3...
column_B2 = val4...
```

When searching you would like to use a conjuntion query on field queries as following

```
query = (column_A1:XX) AND (column_B1:XX)
```

You could find more information [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html) on lucene query syntax.

**EDIT:** Another option consist of two searches might be less performing: 
You could have a first search on the first column collecting all the corresponding titles (id's), and add them to a second query (on the second column):

```
Query: (Column_B1:XX) AND ( id1 OR id2 OR ...)
```

where the Id's are the results collected from the first search.

Comment: All fields indexes into one document, is that your meaning? but i want to index those fields into two documents,not one document. and make a Query that can searching base on the conditions of the two documents. just like: SELECT * FROM Table_A,Table_B WHERE column_primaryKey_A = column_primaryKey_B AND column_A1 = XX AND column_B1 = XX

Comment: No, you should index separate field for each column. This way you'll achieve the same result (as far as I understand your question).
As far as I know there is no way to search with dependencies of separate document, you could do two depended searches (I'll edit my answer).